# UPDATE query fails php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
$db = db_connect();

$title = $_POST['post_title'];
$content = $_POST['post_content'];
$id = $_GET['post'];
$userId = $_GET['id'];


$query =  "UPDATE post";
$query .= "SET title = $title, content=$content";
$query .= "WHERE id= $id";  

$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

//Error handling 
if(!$result) {
    echo  "Query failed" . mysqli_error($connection);
    }
    else {
        echo "Post updated";
    }

db_disconnect($db);
```

The query fails and is not updated in phpmyadmin. I can't see what is going wrong and no error message is given.

Comment: Can you please check the output of the $query variable ? According to your code it'll display something like this "UPDATE postSET title = $title, content=$contentWHERE id= $id". I think its just a space issue but please verify it once by printing the $query variable.

Comment: `mysqli_error($db)`, and error_reporting might have helped.

Comment: *"no error message is given"* - That's because you're not checking for errors on the same connection.  You're also not even examining the runtime value of the query you're executing when you debug.  Note also that your code is *highly vulnerable* to SQL injection, which is not only a security risk but also a very common source of bugs and errors.  It's also *highly unlikely* that the values you're trying to update aren't string values, which would mean you're missing quotes around them.  (Which would be a moot point if you used query parameters... Hence the "common source of bugs and errors".)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is your **only** issue, but you need spaces in your `query`

```
// change this
$query =  "UPDATE post";
$query .= "SET title = $title, content=$content";
$query .= "WHERE id= $id";  

// to this
$query =  "UPDATE post ";
$query .= "SET title = '$title', content='$content' ";
$query .= "WHERE id = '$id'";
```